# Javascript простенькая регулярка

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужна помощь - составить простенькую регулярку:

```
str = 'New/123/папка/123/713'
```

Нужно обрезать строку с конца до символа /. Выражение должно быть универсальное. Благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = 'New/123/папка/123/713';
//разбиваем строку в массив
var arr = str.split('/');
//удаляем последний элемент массива
arr.pop();
//формируем новую строку
var newStr = arr.join('/')+'/';

console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: То что нужно) Благодарен.

Comment: @greg zakharov прекрасно) Но я писал с комментариями, чтобы автор лучше понял логику происходящего и в следующий раз смог воспользоваться этими методами.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "New/123/папка/123/713",
    rgx = /([aA-zZ0-9-]+$)/;
    
console.log(str.replace(rgx, ""));
```

Comment: @gregzakharov спасибо) просили обрезать строку. Можно еще и так `str.slice(0, str.search(/([aA-zZ0-9-]+$)/))`